# iphone ad-hoc distribution on app store

Tags: iphone, app-store, ad-hoc-distribution

I made an error and put an ad-hoc distribution instead of appstore distribution to an appstore approved app.

What are the problems that I might encounter? Will the user who buys the app be entitled to install the app to 100 devices like the ad-hoc distribution? Or is it going to be fine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pretty much count on your app being rejected by Apple for not being signed with the proper certificate.

It may be worthwhile rejecting the current binary and uploading the properly signed distribution binary rather than waiting on Apple to reject.

Comment: By biggest question is how did you get it to upload, it should have failed the singing check and be rejected.

Comment: My app was not rejected btw, it's selling fine (for such kind of app) so It seems that the certificate probably passed (or I had a proper certificate loaded without knowing) or else there is a bug in application loader :)

Comment: On that basis I'd suggest that you indeed signed with the correct certificate from the off and only believed to have made a mistake. If, by some error, an app signed with an ad-hoc profile did manage to slip through the review process you'd get to know pretty quickly; the user wouldn't be able to install the app as their device wouldn't be in the provisioning profile and poor reviews would ensue.

Comment: Since it reaches the point that the user has to download something to make it operational, I assume that it works (also I haven't received any complaint so far).

Answer (score 5):

The same thing happened to me, and the app has sold hundreds of copies with no reviews indicating an incorrect profile.  I imagine either Xcode or Apple fixed it for us, though I'm not certain how.  That said, however, I would update it the next time around.

Comment: It seems like you have both the profiles, so it accepts the app store (distribution) profile. Check to see if you have "get-task-allow: false" on your uploaded binary details. I think that is the difference between ad-hoc and distribution profile.

Comment: At the time of the initial submission, we only had the ad hoc profile.

Comment: Oh yeah, where do I look for those binary details?

Comment: Itunesconnect, Go to product version, and check binary details.

Comment: get-task-allow: false 
aps-environment: production

Comment: It seems fine. get-task-allow is the distribution ad-hoc if it's turned on I think. Anyway, if it's selling then it's ok. I've updated my app and it still doesn't have any problem from apple. Also I did a cleanup of all codesigning (search in stackoverflow for that), so nothing changed. Same options (only 1.1 version).

Answer (score 3):

If you signed it with the wrong certificate, Apple will reject it and it won't be distributed to end users.

I'm surprised that it wasn't immediately rejected on upload to be honest. But if you're sure it's the wrong version you can reject the binary yourself in iTunes Connect.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It seems that it works just fine (as you can see from my other comment above, there is no problem).

Comment: Also for me they didn't reject it.

Answer (score 3):

I accidentally uploaded App to AppStore with AdHoc profile, same as Panagiotis did and app was approved and ready for sale.

Answer (score 2):

Provisioning profile does the following:

- ties your app id to your distribution certificate and optionally a list of devices
- also enforces that the binary matches entitlements like key-chain access group

The difference between adhoc and appstore profiles for the same app:

- the adhoc one includes a list of devices that can install .... adhoc

The certificate, app id and entitlements are EXACTLY the same

Binary:

- Your provisioning profile is embedded into the binary produced from Organizer archive. I have in the past submitted adhoc builds with no issues. And I just done another one yesterday to put my money where my mouth is. Will let you know if it passes the review process.

I'm not advocating to be lazy and just use one profile. Organizer archive does give you the option to re-sign with a specific profile so you have no excuses. And Apple may (or already have) introduce other information in the profiles in future so not worth the risk unless you curious like me.

Comment: The problem is when you develop for someone else and does not want you to have full access to all the features in the provisional services. There are a lot of "development" companies out there with such attitude.